# Store and Retrieve multiple checkbox value from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read the array list from firestore to checkbox widget in flutter, i can print the value in the console and i am struggling to set the value as true for the value which is read from the firestore collection.

**Example Scenario:**

- User need to select the multiple checkbox and the respective value is stored in the firestore collection.
- When the users reopen the app the stored value from the firestore should be retrieved and the respective checkbox should be set true(enabled).

Code:

```
final preferences = [ PreferenceModel(prefName: 'Zone1'),
PreferenceModel(prefName: 'Zone2'),
PreferenceModel(prefName: 'Zone3'),
PreferenceModel(prefName: 'Zone4'),];

Widget buildCheckBox(PreferenceModel preference){
  return buildCheckbox( preference: preference, onClicked: (){
    setState(() {
      final newPrefValue = !preference.prefValue;
      preference.prefValue = newPrefValue;
          });
  });
}

Widget buildCheckbox({@required PreferenceModel preference,@required VoidCallback onClicked}){
 return ListTile(
    //onTap:onClicked,
    leading: Checkbox(
      value: preference.prefValue,
      onChanged: (prefValue){
        if(prefValue == true){
          print(preference.prefName);
          insertData(preference.prefName);
        }else
          removeData(preference.prefName);
        onClicked();
      },
    ),
    title: Text(preference.prefName),
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand. What exactly is the issue and what have you tried to solve it? Please, add the code in which the application reads and writes to Firestore.

Comment: I am trying to store and retrieve the multiple checkbox values to the firestore. i can able to store the checkbox value in array format but i am struck to retrieve the data and display in the respective checkbox field.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: So you are able to store and retrieve the checkboxes status on Firestore but you are unable to set the right status on the checkbox fields?

Comment: Yes you are correct.